# Google Authenticator - missing otpauth protocol parameter

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-oauth, google-authenticator

I'm trying to generate a QR code for the Google Authenticator app for my site (to use for Two-Factor Authentication user login.) I follow [this guideline](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/wiki/KeyUriFormat) to generate a URI (using Google Chart APIs.)

So I made up this URL:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/Example:alice@gmail.com?secret=TGABZXEP4LKB46AX&issuer=Example

that created the QR code (from the link above.)

But when I scan it with the [Google Authenticator app](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447?hl=en) for my iPhone the line I'm getting does not show the issuer (circled in red in this screenshot) like it does for other services -- see Google in other entries:

[image]

So what parameter am I missing there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The otpauth uri must be encoded in the charts url.

`https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth%3A%2F%2Ftotp%2FExample%3Aalice%40gmail.com%3Fsecret%3DTGABZXEP4LKB46AX%26issuer%3DExample`

You can get away with replacing `...&issuer=...` with `...%26issuer=...`, but a properly encoded url is best.